# DbContext requires manual load of navigation properties

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

I recently upgraded my solution from EF5 to EF6.1.2, and changed my data access layer to use DbContext instead of ObjectContext.

Some of my unit tests are failing, and I don't understand why. Example of old data access code:

```
public virtual T Insert(T item)
{
        if (item == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("item", @"TaskDal.Insert");
        }

        using (var ctx = ObjectContextManager<StoreDataContext>.GetManager("StoreDataContext"))
        {
            var task = new Task();
            WriteNonKeyData(task, item);
            ctx.ObjectContext.Tasks.AddObject(task); // task.taskType null
            ctx.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(); // task.TaskType set
            return ReadData(task);
        }
}
```

The `Task` Entity has a navigation property `TaskType`. As commented above, this gets set after the AddObject line.

My new code looks like so:

```
public virtual T Insert(T item)
{
        if (item == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("item", @"TaskDal.Insert");
        }

        using (var ctx = DbContextManager<StoreDataContext>.GetManager())
        {
            var task = new Task();
            WriteNonKeyData(task, item);
            ctx.DbContext.Tasks.Add(task); // task.TaskType null
            ctx.DbContext.SaveChanges(); // task.TaskType still null
            return ReadData(task);
        }
}
```

Unlike the old code, `task.TaskType` is not set, which causes an exception in `ReadData`. LazyLoading is true in both examples.

I can workaround this by manually reloading the `TaskType`:

```
if (task.TaskType == null)
    ctx.DbContext.Entry(task).Reference(p => p.TaskType).Load();
```

but I would prefer a better solution, as I am sure there are hundreds of other places in my code where this will need to be changed and it will be difficult for me to find them all.

Comment: Did your dbmodel change? Do you have any migrations which might have modified the Key property on TaskType? Note that your testproject might have its own app.config with its own connection string (i.e. might point to another database)

Comment: @Default I changed my model to use the new T4 code generation strategy, but there have been no schema changes.

Comment: @Default TaskType entity has correct property as key (Id). Database is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Task` will not load its navigation properties as these are not implemented to be lazily loaded. Take a look at your class definition, do you see any code in the getter? No.

Now, take a look at the model classes created automatically for your legacy code, is there a non empty getter that supports lazy loading? Yes, there is.

The difference is that with code-first, your model classes have no code that supports lazy loading. Lazy loading is supported only on **proxy** objects that are created by the context when you retrieve data from the database.

One of simplest workarounds would be to force the EF to create a proxy for you:

```
    using (var ctx = DbContextManager<StoreDataContext>.GetManager())
    {
        var task = new Task();
        WriteNonKeyData(task, item);

        ctx.DbContext.Tasks.Add(task); // task.TaskType null
        ctx.DbContext.SaveChanges(); // task.TaskType still null

        // let ef create a proxy for the very same database object
        var ptask = ctx.DbContext.Tasks.First( p => p.ID == task.ID );

        // ptask.TaskType is now available as the actual type of
        // ptask is not Task but rather a TaskProxy that inherits from Task
        // and is created automatically by ef

        return ReadData(ptask);
    }
```

Comment: I'm wasn't using a code first approach before. Is T4 implicitly code-first? Unfortunately I have a dependency on CSLA, CSLA.EF6 expects you to use T4, otherwise I would have stayed with legacy.

Comment: This looks very similar to the workaround I showed in my question. Can you explain why this is better?

Comment: It's not better, it's cleaner. First, you don't need `if`, the navigation property will always be `null` on newly created object unless you set it by yourself. Then, you don't really need to reload this one specific navigation property. Better reload the whole object and it will be replaced with a proxy where all possible navigation properties work.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I see what you mean. But, I'm still not sure why replacing ObjectContext with DbContext should require me to add this proxy line into every insert function in my code. I don't understand enough about EF to appreciate what has changed between the code before and after.