# Why does the "Add" method of Entity Framework Collections behave differently across versions?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I just upgraded from EF 4 (Object Context) to EF 6 (dbContext).. and my application throwing exceptions all over the place. I have narrowed it down to this:

user.PaymentMethod.Add(paymentMethod)

In the old version, the paymentMethod.User property was immediately assigned the user Object... but in the new version.. paymentMethod.User is null after this line of code.

I have had to change the code to this:
paymentMethod.User=user

Since many of the subsequent lines of code operate on the user object before SaveChanges() - this is causing havoc everywhere.

Im not sure if the application was written badly, or if there is something fundamental I am missing here about the newer EF version (or dbContext) [apologies Im not sure if its the newer EF version or the change to dbContext that is making the difference here]

Comment: can you provide complete code or code which can be used to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: the `null` value in your `book.Category` lets me think your problem may be related with the eager / lazy loading.

Comment: can you show your category and book entities!!

Comment: Hi Mak, the entities are straight out of Entity Framework

Comment: Have now changes the example objects in the description  to match the code (sorry)

Comment: Looks like the answer can be explained here [in another question][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27921545/dbcontext-requires-manual-load-of-navigation-properties